# Give the center and radius of the points B(1,4) C(-1,2) A(4, -3)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, circles

My procedure:
First, I solved for the slope of line CA. Afterwards, I solved for its Midpoint. Then I formed its equation. 
I also applied the same process to line CB. According to my research, I should subtract the first equation to the second equation. I'm confused because the value of my x was a fraction after subtracting. I decided to make it zero. Then, I used it and solved for the value of y. I got 25/4. I solved for the midpoint by the points C and (0,25/4) I got the center (2,13/5)  I guess converse of angle in a semicircle is involved with this.

I'm probably wrong with my calculation, so I'm open for any corrections. Please explain your answer in detailed. Thank you.

Comment: By center, do you mean the circumcentre?

Comment: Have you tried using the equation of a circle?  Call the center $(h, k)$.  What equations can you write?

Comment: @peterwhy yes you're right

Comment: @N.F Taussig Point B will be (x-1)+(y-4)=r^2 Point C will be (x+1)+(y-2)=r^2 Lastly, point A will be (x-4)+(y+3)=r^2

Comment: What do you mean, you had a fraction, so you made it zero?

Comment: @DougM I subtracted the first equation to the second equation to get the value of x and it turned out to be a fraction. I'm really confused  about this part.

Comment: The equation of a circle with center $(h, k)$ and radius $r$ is $(x - h)^2 + (y - k)^2 = r^2$.  See the hint provided by @peterwhy.

Comment: Sometimes, you get a fraction.  That doesn't give you a reason to call it zero.

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable solving three linear equations in three unknowns, let the equation of the circle be $$(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2 = r^2.$$ Substitute points $A$, $B$ and $C$, you will obtain three linear equations with unknowns $h$, $k$ and $(r^2-h^2-k^2)$.

Comment: I'm sorry our teacher didn't teach us how to solve three linear equations in three unknowns

Answer (score 0):

$\left(\frac{1-1}{2},\frac{4+2}{2}\right)$ or $(0,3)$ is a middle point of $BC$.
$$m_{BC}=\frac{4-2}{1+1}=1.$$
Thus, the center placed in the line: $y-0=-1(x-3)$, which says that $O(x,3-x)$ is our center.

Now, since $OA=OC$, we obtain:
$$(x-4)^2+(6-x)^2=(x+1)^2+(1-x)^2$$ or
$$x^2-8x+16+36-12x+x^2=x^2+2x+1+x^2-2x+1$$ or
$$-20x+52=2,$$
which gives $x=2.5$ and $O(2.5,0.5)$.

From here $R=\sqrt{14.5}$.

Comment: I understand how you come up with the answer 3-x, but how did you get the x? Sorry just confused

Comment: @Janine I fixed my post. See now, please.

Comment: I still don't understand how you got the x of the center O. Also, why isn't it not (x-4)^2+(y-6)^2=(x+1)^2+(y-1)^2

Comment: @Janine $y=3-x$ and $OA=OC$. $OA=\sqrt{(x-4)^2+(y+3)^2}=\sqrt{(x-4)^2+(6-x)^2}$...

Comment: I have a question, is it also possible that OB=OA?

Comment: @Janine Yes of course!

Comment: I know that you used y=3-x to get the value of Y  but why isn't there any Y variable in (x-4)^2+(6-x)^2=(x+1)^2+(1-x)^2 . I have an assumption. A(4, -3) ..you substituted the -3 in 3-x that's why it is 6. You copied the format of 3-x. Is it that's why (x-4)^2+(6-x)^2=(x+1)^2+(1-x)^2 is written like this?

Comment: @Janine I used the following. If $A(a,b)$ and $B(c,d)$ then $AB=\sqrt{(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of a circle with center $(h, k)$ and radius $r$ is 
$$(x - h)^2 + (y - k)^2 = r^2$$
We wish to find an equation of a circle that passes through the points $A(4, -3)$, $B(1, 4)$, and $C(-1, 2)$.  Substituting these points into the equation above yields
\begin{align*}
(4 - h)^2 + (-3 - k)^2 & = r^2 \tag{1}\\
(1 - h)^2 + (4 - k)^2 & = r^2 \tag{2}\\
(-1 - h)^2 + (2 - k)^2 & = r^2 \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Equating the expressions for $r^2$ in equations 1 and 2 yields
$$(4 - h)^2 + (-3 - k)^2 = (1 - h)^2 + (4 - k)^2$$
Expanding and simplifying yields 
\begin{align*}
16 - 8h + h^2 + 9 + 6k + k^2 & = 1 - 2h + h^2 + 16 - 8k + k^2\\
-6h + 14k & = -8\\
3h - 7k & = 4 
\end{align*}
Equating the expressions for $r^2$ in equations 1 and 3 yields
$$(4 - h)^2 + (-3 - k)^2 = (-1 - h)^2 + (2 - k)^2$$
Expanding and simplifying yields
\begin{align*}
16 - 8h + h^2 + 9 + 6k + k^2 & = 1 + 2h + h^2 + 4 - 4k + k^2\\
-10h + 10k & = -20\\
h - k & = 2 
\end{align*}
You can solve for the coordinates of the center by solving the system of linear equations 
\begin{alignat*}{3}
3h & - & 7k & = 4\\
h & - & k & = 2
\end{alignat*} 
Once you have found the center, you can substitute one of the points for $x$ and $y$ in the equation $(x - h)^2 + (y - k)^2 = r^2$ to determine the radius.

Answer (score 0):

Find the lengths of the three sides: $BC=\sqrt{8},AB=\sqrt{58},AC=\sqrt{50}$.

Note it is a right angled triangle: $AB^2=AC^2+BC^2$.

In a right angle triangle the center of circumcircle is the midpoint of the hypotenuse. Thus:
$$R=\frac {AB}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{58}}{2}.$$

Answer (score -1):

Here are two different approaches:

This one seems more direct to me.

There exists a point $X = (x,y)$ such that  $d(X,A) = d(X,B) = d(X,C)$

$(x-4)^2 + (y+3)^2  = (x-1)^2 + (y-4)^2 = (x+1)^2 + (y-2)^2\\
x^2 - 8x + 16 + y^2 + 6x + 9 = x^2 - 2x + 1 + y^2 - 8y + 16 = x^2 + 2x + 1 + y^2 - 4y + 4$

We can subtract $x^2 + y^2$ across the board.

$ - 8x +  6x + 25 =  - 2x  - 8y + 17 =  2x  - 4y +5$

and consolidate a little bit further

$ - 10x +  10x + 20 =  - 4x  - 4y + 12 = 0$

and break this up into two equations.

$ - 10x +  10x + 20 = 0\\
 - 4x  - 4y + 12 = 0$

And solve for $x$ and $y.$

To find the radius.

$r^2 = (x-4)^2 + (y+3)^2  = (x-1)^2 + (y-4)^2 = (x+1)^2 + (y-2)^2$

plug the value of $x,y$ into any of the above.

The approach you suggest works.

Find the lines through the midpoint of $AC$ and $BC,$ with slopes perpendicular to $AC$ and $BC$

Slope of $AC = -1$

Slope of the perpendicular $= 1$

mid-point $= (1.5, -0.5)$

$y+0.5 = x - 1.5\\
-x + y = -2$

Slope of $BC = 1$

Slope of the perpendicular $=-1$

mid-point $= (0, 3)$

$y-3 = - x\\
 x + y = 3$

and again, a system of 2 linear equations.

And you will need to apply a distance formula to find the radius.